# Playing a song from Spotify web app turns off one of my three monitors

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Bit of a weird one.

When I go to spotify.com > sign in > Web Player > and **the moment** I hit the "play" button, one of my three screens (all three screens connected to my HP Thunderbolt - 2 x HDMI and 1 x VGA) will turn off (blank screen but remains powered).

This never happens to other apps to play sound (e.g. iheartradio / youtube) but only Spotify web apps.